# How to read web.config from Web service instead Web.config from Web app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services

The question is simple, I have a web app which calls a web service. Both have its own web.config.

The problem I'm experiencing is I want to read the web.config belonging to the web service, but when I do it on the web service code in reality the web.config being read is the web.config belonging to the web app. 
I think this is due to the application domain, I mean, because the web app is calling the web service. 
This is my code placed on web service:
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["name_connectionString"].ToString()

It returns null because is reading the web.config from web app instead of web.config from web service.

Anybody knows how can I proceed?? I don't find any type of clue at the moment

### Thanks

Edit: My solution stills resides inside Visual Studio. It is formed by:
- Web site containing web references
- Web service
- class library which is called by the web service to read data from databases

Is it possible that as they reside under the same virtual directory/application (eg: Visual Studio) is always reading the web.config from web app?

Comment: I think you should clarify how your solution is set up.

Comment: I've edited the question, maybe now is more clear my problem

Answer (score 1):

If they live under the same virtual directory/application, they will always use the same file.

Comment: Currently my solution resides inside visual studio. It is formed by:

Comment: Currently my solution resides inside visual studio. It is formed by:

Comment: Then I understand if I'm executing this kind of scenario inside visual studio it's not possible to read the Web Service web.config, as bot web app and web service live under the same virtual directory/application. Am I right?

Comment: @user354427: If I understand you right (for some reason) you want to call your web service from you web app, while the web service lives in the same place. Yes, it should be quite possible, all the configuration will live in the web.config. You might have to remove one of the Global HttpApplication classes from either project to make them live happily together.

Answer (score 1):

There could be only one web.config per application. So if you have a separate web.config for your service you might need to setup a web method which returns the desired values and call this web method from your application.